# editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0] don't return the same result in IE11

Tags: ckeditor, internet-explorer-11

I have been looking into this issue for a few hours now and I can't find a way to fix it. I am using `ckeditor 4.3`(also try 4.5) with a custom colour picker to change font colour.

All work well in `chrome`, `firefox`, `opera` and `safari` yet not in `IE`. The problem come from

```
editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0].startContainer
```

which gave me a `span` in chrome which is what I want and `p` in `IE` which is one level high.

Here a litle exemple :

```
_me.editor.focus();
var range = _me.editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
AddLinkColor(range.startContainer, value.Value);

var AddLinkColor = function (element, color)
{
    var selectedChild = null;
    if (element.getChildren) { selectedChild = element.getChildren(); }
    if (selectedChild)
    {
        if (selectedChild.count)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedChild.count() ; i++)
            {
                var childElement = selectedChild.getItem(i);
                if (childElement.getStyle && childElement.getStyle('color')      != '' && childElement.getStyle('color') != color) childElement.setStyle('color',` color);
                if (childElement.getChildCount && childElement.getChildCount() > 0) AddLinkColor(childElement, color);
                if (element.$.tagName == 'A') element.setStyle('color', color);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Any other face the same issue?

I have tried all the variant of `startContainer` that gave a dom element, like commonAncestor and such still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea I was afraid so, thanks, made a litle fix not quite sexy but it work

```
 if(element.getName() != "span") {  selectedChild = element.getChildren().getItem(0).getChildren(); }    
 else {   selectedChild = element.getChildren();  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection behaves differently in different browsers, because there's no specification as well as the platforms behave differently in general. As long as the results reflect the real position of the selection everything is fine. That's nothing surprising and nothing to worry about. The only problem is that you need to handle all those different selections and this makes creating an editor so hard. Therefore, [CKEditor API](http://docs.ckeditor.com) contains many tools to simplify this job.